# Particle system to one mesh - and keep materials?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

I have created a particle system with an emitter emitting Lego pieces and filled a big box with these Lego pieces. *Object Info > Randomize* on the colors of the Lego pieces with 5 colors on Ramp.

When emitted I convert the particle system to mesh and join all the meshes (all the Lego pieces), but all the Lego pieces turns into one color only.

Is this because of the 16 material limit? Any way to get this conversion done and keep all the different colors of the pieces?

Answer (score 1):

*Object Info > Random* works with different objects. So when you join all objects, It becomes one object and *Randomize* will give only single value for that.

If you do not join objects into one then *Object > Random* will work.

If you want to join all objects, What you can use here is *Geometry* node's *Random per Island* input. Keep in mind *Random per Island* is Cycles only, see
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html